# How to concatenate two files in a new one and sort the output in one line

Tags: sort, cat

I have two files with some names in them, when I ran `cat file1 file2 | sort`, the terminal shows the names sorted alphabetically, but when I run `cat file1 file2 > file3 | sort` I don't see the sorted output, why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have already redirected the output of `file1` and `file2` to the new file `file3`.

With this command `cat file1 file2 > file3 | sort`, `sort` after pipe.

This could be verified as below.

```
cat file1
A
Z
B
cat file2
F
G
C
```

Now when I run the command as, `cat file1 file2 > file3 | sort` we could see that the contents of `file1` and `file2` are written to `file3` but it is not sorted.

I believe what you are trying to achieve could be fairly easily accomplished as,

```
cat file1 file2 | sort > file3
```

However, it doesn't show the output in the console window.

If you need the output of two files after sorted to be written to a new file and at the same time the sorted output to be available in the console, you could do something like below.

```
cat file1 file2 | sort > file3; cat file3
```

However, it is good to make use of `tee` in this case. `tee` could be effectively used as,

```
cat file1 file2 | sort | tee file3
```

The above command basically concatenates 2 files and sorts them and displays the output in the console and at the same time writes the output of the pipe to the new file specified using the `tee` command.

As user [casey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53706/casey) points out, if you have `zsh` shell available on your system, you could use the below command as well.

```
sort <file1 <file2 | tee file3
```

Answer (score 4):

POSIX defines the `sort` utility's purpose so:

> Sort lines of all the named files together and write the result to the specified output.

You can sort  two files into a concatenated output file like:

```
sort $opts file1 file2 >output_file
```

If you want to see the output on your shell's `stdout` *and* save the results in an output file then use `tee`:

```
sort $opts file[12] | tee output_file
```

Comment: you always have an unique way of approaching things. I like that :)

Comment: @Ramesh A lot of standard UNIX commands take files as arguments. People overuse `cat` so much that there are actually pages listing redundant usages of it. Here's one such page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: @gparent, I think you have put the comment in the wrong place. And anyways, the point you refer to is a valid point and I have got rid of the useless use of cat. And I believe the `zsh` and `tee` approach in the answer should be effective and they do not overuse the cat.

Comment: Ah, on my end I still see usage of `cat | sort` rather than `sort`. My bad.